# Saving managed object context creates deadlock in iOS 5's performBlock

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, deadlock, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've been looking for a solution for this problem for a long time and have yet reached one.

I'm developing an iOS app with core data. I've created two managed object contexts (MOC) which point to the same persistent store coordinator. One MOC (referred as self.moc) is initiated with main queue concurrency whereas the other mov (referred as self.bmoc) is initiated with private queue concurrency. I've made sure that self.moc only runs on the main thread and self.bmoc only runs within its `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` block.

However, I've encountered this strange situation where my app freezes on the `[self.bmoc save:nil]` line. Since the save action is executed within the `performBlock` block, I don't see a reason for it to reach a deadlock. Since it freezes on that line, I can't receive an error even if I use `[self.bmoc save:&error]` rather than `nil`.

Below is the code which will reproduce the problem. Although I have many functions similar to the one below, only **this one** creates the problem. I fail to figure the cause of the problem and any insight is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
-(void)createEmptyUserData {
    [self.bmoc performBlock:^{
        User* user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.bmoc];
        /* sets user object */
        [self.bmoc save:nil];
    }];
}
```

Note: This piece of code is executed in main thread.

Comment: Any insight where the deadlock occur? Any validateSomething method or willSave method locking something? Deadlock means 2 threads are waiting on each other, where is the other thread waiting?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After this piece of code is executed, main thread continues on and ends up at `[self.bmoc performBlockAndWait^{}]`, where it waits for the code above to finish its execution, causing the main thread to freeze. I'm not aware of having any validateSomething methods or willSave methods.

Comment: You could try adding `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` to turn on debugging and see if anything is actually getting saved.

Comment: Also perhaps this block is actually waiting for a previous block to finish and that's the one that's stuck?

Comment: Are the contexts nested or do they just share the same persistent t store coordinator?

Comment: What do you mean by "private queue concurrency"?  If you mean it runs in parallel on its own GCD queue or NSOperationQueue, you might have a problem since you can't guarantee which thread an operation/GCD block runs on.

Comment: @Rory O'Bryan It appears to me that the data was indeed saved. Since I surround this block with `performBlock`, if it is waiting for some other block to finish, shouldn't it wait at the beginning of `performBlock` rather than `save`?

Comment: @svena can you explain what do you mean by nested contexts? To me they share the same persistent store coordinator. I did `[moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.psc]` for both MOCs.

Comment: @JeremyP What I meant was that I initialized `self.bmoc` with `[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];`. This is new in iOS 5 and from what I've learned, as long as I perform coredata related actions in `performBlock`, I shouldn't have any threading problem. But apparently this problem proved that that's not that case . Thank you all for your help!

Comment: By nested contexts I meant a pattern where you would have a root context which is responsible for the persistent store and another context would be a child context of the root context. Why I even mentioned this is because in "WWDC2012 Session 214 - Core Data Best Practices" Apple engineers explicitly warned NOT to use -performBlockAndWait: on child context from within a block of root context since that could easily cause a deadlock.

Comment: I had a deadlock using nested contexts in UIManagedDocument which turned out to be due to saving the UIManagedDocument (not the context) from the private background thread instead of the main thread.  As per Jody's suggestion it was pretty easy to spot in the debugger from looking at the different threads at the point of deadlock in Xcode.  Definitely a good place to investigate from.

Comment: @svena I see. Although no, I don't have nested contexts, but I am indeed having problems of the same type (and I have figured out my problem: see comment under Jody's answer). I have yet gotten a chance to see "WWDC2012 Session 214 - Core Data Best Practices" but I'll do so in the upcoming time before asking questions like this. Thank you!

Comment: @Rory O'Bryan I'm kind of new to objective-c (although I have experiences in C/C++) and xcode. And to be honest, I don't find xcode's debugging interface to be that helpful. However, it may be that I don't know how to use it correctly, but it seems that I should learn how to use it, as it may, as you say, provide helpful information. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic reasons for you to get a "hang" in that situation.

1. You have a nested call to performBlockAndWait or some other synchronous thread/queue call.
2. One of your blocks is not returning, and running forever.

Both of these can be easily seen by looking at the stacks of each running thread at the time of the "hang."

performBlock simply takes the execution block and adds it to a queue, then it returns immediately.  Some other thread is then popping execution blocks off the queue and executing them.

performBlockAndWait executes in the context of the calling thread.  Basically, it waits for currently enqueued execution blocks to run, then it runs the requested code on the current thread.

It des not return until the call is complete.

So, I'd bet you either have multiple nested calls to performBlockAndWait OR one of your asynchronous execution blocks is not completing.

Look at the stack at the time of the hang...

Alternatively, log your block execution, so you can see when each block starts and exits.

Comment: This is similar to what fabrice truillot de chambrier had said. I'll dig into the problem with the direction you provide and get back to you later. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to the answer. I'll edit this later and provide some details on the cause of the problem and how I solved it.

Comment: I thought I can edit comments, but apparently I'm wrong. Anyways, the cause of the problem is that `[self.bmoc save:nil];` calls `contextDidChange:` after the saving process is done. In my `contextDidChange:`, I had `[self.moc performBlockAndWait^{ //mergeContext }]`. As I mentioned in comment under my question, my main thread continues on and ends up at `[self.bmoc performBlockAndWait^{}]`. The problem should become clear: both queues are waiting for each other to finish, thus causing a deadlock. My solution is to change `performBlockAndWait` in `contextDidChange:` to `lock` and `unlock`.

Comment: Is contextDidChange: your notification handler?  I'd favor calling [self.moc performBlock^{ /* whatever */ }]; over explicit locking.

Comment: Yes. Since `[self.moc performBlock^{ /* whatever */ }]` causes a deadlock, I figure that I have to use explicit lock.

Comment: No... performBlock just tosses the block on a queue, and returns immediately.  performBlockAndWait is the cause of the deadlock.

Comment: Since I need to have contexts merged after each `[moc save:]`, so I choose `performBlockAndWait:` rather than `performBlock`. The reason for that is, for example, after my `self.bmoc` saved fetched data from the internet, my `self.moc` needs to access the data immediately and updates the user interface.